# Canvas performance written by hand vs engines

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm currently developing games as HTML5 canvas applications and they perform fine on Chrome; however Firefox and Opera both produce noticeable delays on the simplest drawing routines (drawing 50 images, for example, 32x32) The iPad and Android Chrome perform OK.. subpar. Worse than Opera and Firefox on the desktop as well.

I see people are achieving 60 FPS on tilemap engines, even at higher resolutions. My question is: how is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've asked a question that has ten million answers.

Good performance is the culmination of a lot of things, starting with writing performant JavaScript in the first place, good coding practices, careful use of the Canvas API and sometimes clever hacks.

If you want to improve performance:

1. Grab a copy of High Performance JavaScript by Zakas
2. [Read the HTML5rocks article on Canvas performance](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/). Some of [my articles](http://simonsarris.com/blog/tag/performance) are referenced there.
3. Use the JavaScript profilers that come with browsers to pinpoint what, exactly, is slowing down your code
4. Show us your code and ask specific questions!

Comment: I had read the HTML5Rocks article a few times - but I missed something extremely important at the bottom.. thanks for re-linking me. As it turns out, my 800x600 static backgrounds is perfectly acceptable in my DirectX based games as the GPU spits these out quite quickly - but when it comes to canvas many browsers love to choke on these.. I'm seeing a huge performance increase rendering these on the background and leaving them alone.